# Sqoop import from NON-DEFAULT schema Netezza

Tags: hive, sqoop, netezza

I want to import a Netezza table in a specific non-default schema with the following command:

```
sqoop import \
    --connect jdbc:netezza://netezza-host-name:5480/NZDATABASE \
    --table MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE \
    --username user \
    -P \
    --hive-import \
    --hive-database demo \
    --create-hive-table \
    --hive-table MY_NEW_TABLE
```

This however fails because because it checks only the default schema "ADMIN":

> org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: ERROR:  relation does not exist NZDATABASE.ADMIN.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE

versions:

- Sqoop 1.4.7
- nzjdbc.jar release 7.2.1.8 driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the environment to test it but two more options which you can try:

1. Specify the schema name in the JDBC connection string:

```
jdbc:netezza://netezza-host-name:5480/NZDATABASE?currentSchema=MY_SCHEMA

or

jdbc:netezza://netezza-host-name:5480/NZDATABASE?searchpath=MY_SCHEMA

or

jdbc:netezza://netezza-host-name:5480/NZDATABASE;schema=MY_SCHEMA
```

2. Pass the --schema argument into the subsystem:

```
`-- --schema MY_TABLE` - two sets of '--' are needed there
```

so the full command will be the following:

```
sqoop import \
    --connect jdbc:netezza://netezza-host-name:5480/NZDATABASE \
    --table MY_TABLE \
    -- --schema MY_TABLE \
    --username user \
    -P \
    --hive-import \
    --hive-database demo \
    --create-hive-table \
    --hive-table MY_NEW_TABLE
```

Comment: Only option 1c works (`...;schema=MY_SCHEMA`) where I need to put the full connection string between double quotation marks

Comment: option 1a and 1b result in the error described in my question

Comment: option 2 results in: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Username`

Comment: do you have a reference to any documentation of the solution?